# How do you add a bash script to your PATH variable using symlinks?

Tags: bash, shell, symlink, path, command

I run a gaming server called PocketMine. So basically I have a folder in my home directory that has a bash script to run the server: `~/PocketMine/start.sh`

Everytime I want to run the server I either `cd` into the folder and `./start.sh` or `PocketMine/./start.sh`

I want to know how do I add a symlink called `pocketmine` in `/usr/local/sbin` (a lot of progs with symlinks goes here) that will run `start.sh` and use the contents of its dir.

`/usr/local/sbin/pocketmine` = `~/PocketMine/./start.sh`

Call me lazy but im tired of cd-ing into the folder and running the script instead of just typing one command.

Comment: As the below answers have illustrated without comment, you never need to say anything quite like `PocketMine/./start.sh`.  You sometimes need **`./`** in front of a plain filename that is in the current directory (i.e., after you have done `cd PocketMine`); in this example, to make explicit your desire to run a program from a directory that's not in your search path.  But specifying any directory (i.e., anything with a **`/`** in it) will do that, so you can say `PocketMine/start.sh` if you are in your home directory, or `~/PocketMine/start.sh` wherever you are, without using the **`/./`**.

Answer (score 5):

You actually don't need any symlinks, just edit your `~/.bashrc` and add the following statement:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/PocketMine
```

This avoids polluting your filesystem with unnecessary clutter like symlinks. If you are a csh/tcsh user rather than a bash user, then edit `~/.cshrc` and add

> set path = ( $path ~/PocketMine )

Personally I'd go one step further in organization. I'd create a `~/bin` directory, and put your start script in there, perhaps with a more distinctive name like `pmstart` (it's not significant that it's a shell script, is it? Maybe someday you want to re-implement it in Python or something. `.sh` suffices on executables are usually a bad idea because you're exposing and hard-coding an implementation detail (the implementation language) that end-users don't care about, and in the process committing yourself to that implementation detail unnecessarily).

It's likely your $PATH already includes $HOME/bin, but if not you can add it similarly.

Finally, there's are historical conventions/best practices as to what things go into `sbin` directories and what things go into `bin` directories. `sbin` is usually reserved for tools for administrators, while `bin` is for general end-user utilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a shorter way to run `~/PocketMine/start.sh`, you can make an alias for it. Add the following line in `~/.bashrc` and call `pm` to run that script:

```
alias pm=~/PocketMine/start.sh
```

If you need to change to the script's directory first, make it a function:

```
function pm (
  cd ~/PocketMine && exec ./start.sh "$@"
)
```

If you want to be able to call this shortcut from another script and not just from an interactive shell, make the shortcut a script that you put in any of the directories in `$PATH`. The script needs to be an executable file (e.g. `chmod a+rx ~/bin/pm`) and contains

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/PocketMine && exec ./start.sh "$@"
```